# Is it true $ABA=A \Rightarrow BAB=B$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Is it true  $ABA=A  \Rightarrow  BAB=B$ ?

$A$ and $B$ are nonzero matrice.

If $A$ is invertible the statement is obvious. What if $A$ is singular?

Comment: That $ABA=A$ in general does  not imply that $BAB=B$, is shown in the answers below. Let $ABA=A$ and put $B_1=BAB$, then it iseasy to see that $AB_1A=A$ and $B_1AB_1=B_1.$

Answer (score 6):

Let $A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$ and $B=I_2$. This matrix $A$ satisfies $A^2=A$.

Hence $ABA=A^2=A$ but $BAB=A \ne B$.